# c# mysql - there is already an open datareader associated with this connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql

```
private void populateTreeView(TreeView tv)
    {
        try
        {
            String query = "select * from year_grade order by sort asc";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            String query1 = "";
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["year_grade"].ToString());
                query1 = "select * from stud_year where year_grade='" + dr["year_grade"] + "' ";
                cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query1, conn);
                dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    node.Nodes.Add(dr["stud_year"].ToString());
                    tv.Nodes.Add(node);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            dr.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception n)
        {
            Console.Write(n.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(n.Message);
        }
    }
```

> what's wrong with this codes. the messagebox from the catch block says " there is already an open datareader associated with this connection which must be closed first".
>   please help guys...

Comment: Its bad practice to not use sql parameters and to also use `*` to select all fields....

Comment: what do you mean by not use sql parameters sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let it close Datareader before connection and not the inverse like in your code. Declare a new datareader and a new command too.
Invert this:
dr.Close();
conn.Close();

Change your code with this one:

```
private void populateTreeView(TreeView tv) 
{ 
    try 
        { 
            String query = "select * from year_grade order by sort asc"; 
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn); 
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            String query1 = ""; 
            while (dr.Read()) 
            { 
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["year_grade"].ToString()); 
                query1 = "select * from stud_year where year_grade='" + dr["year_grade"] + "' "; 
                cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query1, conn); 
                dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader(); 
                while (dr2.Read()) 
                { 
                    node.Nodes.Add(dr2["stud_year"].ToString()); 
                    tv.Nodes.Add(node); 
                } 
                                dr2.Close();
            }
```

`dr.Close();
                    conn.Close(); 

    }
    catch (Exception n)
    {
        Console.Write(n.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(n.Message);
    }`

}

Answer (score 1):

you need to define a new DataReader for inner loop because the previous reader is already open.

Comment: sir, actually i did already that, the first thing i did was, define another datareader. (dr1 for example). but nothings change the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message implies the connection only permits one active reader at a time. If this was SQL Server, you'd need to include `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in your connection string. For MySQL you'll need to do whatever the equivalent is (assuming it supports this feature).

Answer (score 1):

In my case (dapper + mysql), i forgot to put semicolon ';' at end of query statement. Error is gone after I put it back.

Comment: Hi, welcome. This question is over 5 years old; it may be better to look for newer questions. Notice that the error does not have to do with the syntax, but with the connection. The first query has executed, and there is an attempt to loop over the results in that `DataReader` to perform additional queries for each result. However, `conn` is being reused when it is passed to the constructor of the `MySqlCommand` object, and the exception is raised when attempting to execute that command -- according to the error, that apparently is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

declare a dataset and fill it with "select * from stud_year ";

inside your inner loop filter it's datatable with "year_grade='" + dr["year_grade"] + "' ";
and loop through it's row

it seems to be better